# QVector operator[] has no member values

Tags: c++, qt, operators, constants, qvector

I am trying to save data to a member value [similarly to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972390/change-object-of-a-qvector-in-an-ordinary-for-loop)

I have a QVector of objects which hold a member variable. Using `.at()` is forbidden as I am trying to convert a const, `.value()` does not save the changes as it is only an instance.

I am try to use the [] operator to return a non-const reference to the object, in order to change the value of the member variable how ever I am getting the error

```
class QVector<Object>' has no member named 'value'
                 objects[i].value = newValue;
                           ^
```

Here is the code snippet causing the error with a shortened class:

```
void Class::linkValueToObject(QVector<Object>* objects, QStringList* data )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < object->size(); ++i )
        for( int j = 0; j < data->size(); ++j )
            if( conditionMet )
            {
                newValue = data.at(j)
                objects[i].value = newValue //Line of error
                break;
            }
}

class Object
{
public:
    QString value;    
}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: QString value is private

Comment: I think you want to write `(*objects)[i].value` and `value`is private (but you will get another error for that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to set a new value to `value`, you are actually not dereferencing `objects`. You need to use `*`operator to do so.

```
void Class::linkValueToObject(QVector<Object>* objects, QStringList* data )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < object->size(); ++i )
        for( int j = 0; j < data->size(); ++j )
            if( conditionMet )
            {
                newValue = data.at(j)
                (*objects)[i].value = newValue //Line of error
                break;
            }
}
```